# Help finding a Noam Elimelech

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, chasidut-hasidism, agada-stories-legends, maseches-makos, noam-elimelech

I recently finished Meseches Makkos and went through the [Agadetahs](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=24&format=pdf) (Summed up very quickly) of when Raban Gamliel, Rabbi Elazar Ben Azaria, Rabbi Yehoshua and Rabbi Akiva were together and Rabbi Akiva laughed, while the other Tannaim cried whereupon Rabbi Akiva gives his reasons why he laughed.

I recall seeing a [Noam Elimelech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimelech_of_Lizhensk) Al HaTorah where he discusses this Agaditah but I can't seem to find it. I believe its in the end of Sefer VaYikra or in the beginning of Bamidbar.

If someone knows where it is I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Not aware of such a discussion from the *No'am Elimelech*, but the *P'ri Tzadik* (*D'varim*) discusses this gemara: "היינו כי רבי עקיבא היה השורש של חכמת תורה שבעל פה... ועל ידי זה היתה נפשו מרגשת מראיית החורבן דייקא את הנחמות הנבנה על ידה יותר מרבי אלעזר ורבי יהושע וזה שאמרו לו בלשון הזה עקיבא נחמתנו שדייקא על ידי בחינתו וכוחו הופיע גם בהם כח הנחמה".

Comment: Tried finding it...no luck. Did you see Fred's answer?

Comment: @EzraHoerster I saw Fred 's answer.  I'm actually looking for it to contrast the second last Aruch LaNer on the Mesechta (link: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14412&st=&pgnum=86&hilite=) where he speaks in terms of Tzaddikim.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni - Ah I see. By the way, nice username. ;)

Comment: The sefer is at http://hebrewbooks.org/19056 .I tried searching in it for your subject without success. Maybe you will have better luck.

Comment: I searched too but the OCR is not famous, the sefer is also in Wikitext and I don't find there too.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni Do you recall generally what the *No'am Elimelech* says? What idea are you trying to develop from the *No'am Elimelech*? Adding this information to your question will help people hone in on what you're looking for. For example: The *P'ri Tzadik* above mentions how R' Akiva's penetrating Torah perspective allowed him to see the destruction itself as a sign of future rebuilding and impending consolation. Is that what you're looking for? The *No'am Elimelech* (*B'har*) cites *Rosh HaShana* 23a about the irreplaceability of R' Akiva and his colleagues. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Fred I think thats it. Is it possible if you can link it here? I don't remember the concept so clearly (being that the Noam Elimelech is hard to understand also) but I recall the citation.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Thank you. Its not the most original, I think there's another Ploni Almoni around on Judaism SE.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni It doesn't address the gemara in *Makos* directly. It's a homiletical interpretation of the verses about redeeming land in *Eretz Yisra'el*. The *No'am Elimelech* uses the idea "צדיק גוזר והקב"ה מקיים" to indicate that HaShem accedes to all the wishes of the loftiest category of *tzadikim* (like R' Akiva and his colleagues) regarding the ultimate redemption of the Jewish people, return to the Land, and rebuilding of the Temple. Since they were executed, however, HaShem must now act of His own accord (as it were) to avenge these *tzadikim* and bring the *g'ula* for His Name's sake.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni The *No'am Elimelech* begins on [this page](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38141&st=&pgnum=83) and continues on to the next page.